Latex Flowchart with Multiple Splits
I try to make this flowchart in Latex but do not know how to make the boxes that go down to the left. Please help as I provide code below as far as I could get to.
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}    

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        > = latex',
        every node/.style={
            draw,
            minimum width=2cm,
            minimum height=0.8cm,
        },
    ]
%
\node (S1) {Step 1};
%
\node[below=of S1] (S2) {Step 2};
\node[below=of S1, left=of S2] (S3) {Step 3};
\node[below=of S1, right=of S2] (S4) {Step 4};

\node[below=of S2] (S2a) {Step 2a};
\node[below=of S3] (S3a) {Step 3a};
\node[below=of S4] (S4a) {Step 4a};

\node[below=of S2a] (S2b) {Step 2b};
\node[below=of S3a] (S3b) {Step 3b};
\node[below=of S4a] (S4b) {Step 4b};

\node[below=of S2b] (S2c) {Step 2c};
\node[below=of S3b] (S3c) {Step 3c};
\node[below=of S4b] (S4c) {Step 4c};


\node[below=of S2c] (S2d) {Step 2d};
\node[below=of S3c] (S3d) {Step 3d};
\node[below=of S4c] (S4d) {Step 4d};


\draw[->] 
(S1) edge (S2)
(S2) edge (S3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


You could add the branches like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}    

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        > = latex',
        every node/.style={
            draw,
            minimum width=2cm,
            minimum height=0.8cm,
        },
    ]
%
\node (S1) {Step 1};
\node[below=of S1] (S2) {Step 2};

\draw[->] (S1) -- (S2);

\node[below left=of S1,yshift=0.9cm] (X1) {X1};
\draw[->] (S1) |- (X1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



thank you! how can i make the part like at the very bottom where it splits into two?

please advise if possible thanks so much!

It works just the same (but your question explicitly asks about "how to make the boxes that go down to the left", you shouldn't ask new questions in comments)

@ samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you I do not know if it counts as new question since it is in original question, if you have any insights that would be so helpful. Also alternatively I can make new question if you like
